# Can nginx do transparent compression of websocket connections?

Tags: nginx, websocket, proxy, compression, gzip

I have nginx acting as reverse-proxy for an ASP.net / Kestrel back-end server.

I'd like nginx to do gzip compression (ie, permessage-deflate / rfc7692) for my Websocket connections, but I can't find any config options for that.

Can nginx do that? Are there any plugins to make it work? If no, is there something else I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is 'no'.

There's nothing in the core nginx modules that supports websockets, and compression in particular.
The config provided by @m00ny's answer is for proxied http requests, it won't have any effect on websockets.

Answer (score 0):

just edit your nginx config. It is the same for static sites, proxies or websockets

```
gunzip on; // be sure to include this. This enables runtime decompression for clients that do not accept gzip
gzip on; //enables gzip for request
gzip_proxied any; //enables compression on proxies
gzip_types *; //compress everything there is
```

if this does not work, try compressing the messages befor sending them through  the socket.
You can read more about it here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/